# VBA - Argument Not Optional Error on Code

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to write a VBA code that checks if a cell has an image and if it does print something (could be anything, in this case I chose a number 1) in the same row as the image, in column #6.

I keep getting the "Argument not Optional" Error on the first line of the sub. Curious if someone can help me! Thank you!!

```
Function CellImageCheck(CellToCheck As Range) As Integer
' Return 1 if image exists in cell, 0 if not

    Dim wShape As Shape

    For Each wShape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If wShape.TopLeftCell = CellToCheck Then
            CellImageCheck = 1
        Else
            CellImageCheck = 0
        End If
    Next wShape

End Function

Sub testFunction()
Dim i As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = 3 To 10 Step 1
    If CellImageCheck(Cells(i, 1)) Then
        Cells(i, 6) = CellImageCheck
    Else
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You need an argument, a range that you're passing to `CellImageCheck`. You can't leave it out the 2nd time you call `CellImageCheck`.

Comment: BTW: TRUE in VBA is `-1`

Comment: I would change the 1 and 0 to `True` and `False` and return a Boolean.  Then pass the return to a variable, test the variable and you can then set the value of the variable to the cell.  Also, not that in the loop `CellImageCheck` will end up being what ever the last shape is.  You need to add an exit loop after finding True.

Comment: @ScottCraner What would this code look like? Do you mind helping me out with the return, test and exit loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment:

```
Function CellImageCheck(CellToCheck As Range) As Boolean
' Return True if image exists in cell, False if not
    CellImageCheck = False
    
    Dim wShape As Shape
    For Each wShape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If wShape.TopLeftCell.Address = CellToCheck.Address Then
            CellImageCheck = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next wShape

End Function

Sub testFunction()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change this to the sheet being tested.
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 3 To 10 Step 1
            Dim bl As Boolean
            bl = False
            bl = CellImageCheck(.Cells(i, 1))
            
            If bl Then .Cells(i, 6) = bl
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This seems like it should work but it's giving me true for a row where there isn't an image. Any insight into why that might be?

Comment: Then step through and find why, without the worksheet I cannot test.

Comment: @ORitt try the edit. I made it a little more robust.

Comment: It's still not working. It returns true for everything, but thank you for your help!!

Comment: @ORitt see edit.  I changed it to check the address instead of the value.

Comment: it works i guess we needed to add address. Thank you so, so much! very appreciated!